# KeyError: "['1'] not found in axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently creating a dataframe. The dataframe currently looks like this:

[image: df visual]

But when I run:

```
g.drop('1', axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

I get the title error: `KeyError ...`

I want to remove the 1's from the `dataframe`, and they currently only exist in the first row of the multi-index `dataframe`.

Comment: Column is probably an int and not a string

Comment: How should I redo the drop command to accomodate?

Comment: `df.drop(columns=1, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

1 is probably int so:

```
g.drop(1, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```